# How to avoid null pointer exception while testing data

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce

I have to apply an algorithm on a data set. The data set consists of two types of objects, each with a particular ID.

Here you can find my first type of object :

```
public static List<ObjectType1> getObjectType1() {
List<ObjectType1> myList = new ArrayList<ObjectType1>();

//Creating one ObjectType1 with ID : 1L
ObjectType1 obj1 = new ObjectType1();
obj1.setId(1L);

//Creating one ObjectType1 with ID : 2L
ObjectType1 obj2 = new ObjectType1();
obj2.setId(2L);

//Creating one ObjectType1 with ID : 3L
ObjectType1 obj3 = new ObjectType1();
obj3.setId(3L);

myList.add(obj1);
myList.add(obj2);
myList.add(obj3);

return myList;
}
```

And this is the second type of object :

```
public static List<ObjectType2> getObjectType2(){
List<ObjectType2> myList = new ArrayList<ObjectType2>();

//Creating one ObjectType2 with ID : 1L
ObjectType2 obj1 = new ObjectType2();
obj1.setId(1L)

//Creating one ObjectType2 with ID : 2L
ObjectType2 obj2 = new ObjectType2();
obj2.setId(2L)

//Creating one ObjectType2 with ID : 4L
ObjectType2 obj3 = new ObjectType2();
obj3.setId(4L)

myList.add(obj1);
myList.add(obj2);
myList.add(obj3);

return myList;
}
```

What I need to do is to apply a simple algorithm on it, but my main problem is that I have a null pointer exception as soon as a try to do it.

Let me explain :
I want to sort all the ObjectType1. Thos that have the same ID as ObjectType2, I keep them. That means if ObjectType1 ID (which is Long : 1L for the first) is present in one of the ObjectType2 --> Ikeep it.
If ObjecType1 ID is not present is one of the ObjectType2 --> we don't keep it.
How can I make this simple "sort" ?

So far I wanted to do is that :

```
    while (valueIterator.hasNext()) {
        value = valueIterator.next();

        if (value instanceof ObjectType1) {
            objType1 = ObjectType1.newBuilder((ObjectType1) value).build();
        } else if (value instanceof ObjectType2){
            objType2 = ObjectType2.newBuilder((ObjectType2) value).build();
        }
    }

    for(ObjectType1 obj : objs){
        if (objType1.getId().equals(objType2.getId())) {
            keep(objType1);
        } else if (objType1.getId() != objType2.getId()) {
            dontKeep(objType1);
        }
    }
```

My Null Pointer Exception appens here `if (objType1.getId().equals(objType2.getId()))` because when I try to get the ID '3L' of objType2  it does not exist...

How can I properly make my sort without my data set ? I can not find a way to loop properly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just make sure you don't call methods on instances you haven't instantiated yet.
if you doubt:
if ( myInstance != null ) myInstance.getId();

Comment: what is the value of `objs`  and also there is no any usage of loop variable you used `obj`

Comment: What I should typically have is obj1 & obj2 kept because ID 1L 2L all present in ObjType2. And obj3 not kept because there is no ID 3L is objType2.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice trick to avoid null pointer exception. Here it is -

```
public List<SomeObject> someMethodReturnsSomeObjects(){

 List<SomeObject> lists = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

 return (null!=lists ? lists : Collections.EMPTY_LIST);

}
```

Here you also need to test against `null`.  But the benefit of this code snippet is that you only need to check `null` only in one place for example in your `ObjectType1.newBuilder((ObjectType1) value).build()` method while returning `objectType1`. But after that you never need to check against null since you are sure that your method never returns null. Now you never need to use `null` checking of the client code of `ObjectType1.newBuilder((ObjectType1) value).build()`.

Moreover you can do the trick most of the data type for example -
**for String:** `return (null != str ? str : "");`
**for Map :** `return (null != map ? map : Collections.EMPTY_MAP);`
**for Set :** `return (null != map ? map : Collections.EMPTY_SET);`
or for other user defined data type you can create your own dummy data like EMPTY_MAP or EMPTY_LIST.

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks Razib, but I don't get the idea there. I do not need to change the data set. What is important is to collect the ObjectType1 according to my algorithm.

Comment: So you are returning an object of  ObjectType1. In this case you can create a dummy objectType1 if objectType1 is null.